# authorization error azure container services

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I'm new to DevOps. Any help on this error is highly appreciated.

When I try to create and deploy DevOps project on Azure I'm receiving the following error.

I'm following steps in this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-aks

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "Conflict",
      "message": {
        "status": "Failed",
        "error": {
          "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
          "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
          "details": [
            {
              "code": "DeploymentFailed",
              "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
              "details": [
                {
                  "code": "BadRequest",
                  "message": {
                    "code": "InvalidRequestValue",
                    "message": "Failed to create the project 'xxxxxxx'. More details: 'Configuration failed at step: 'Configuring release pipeline'. More details: Failed to acquire authorization token. Details: [AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.Trace ID: 5cebc087-cb41-4b95-bc72-3c55cf250400 Correlation ID: 2a51cf8c-c8b1-420d-84a2-e50ca8193044 Timestamp: 2018-08-01 09:07:39Z]. ResponseCode: Unauthorized.'.",
                    "target": "ProcessCompletedJob"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You got the error from which step in the article?

Comment: under "Configure VSTS and an Azure subscription"

Comment: at the time of deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, AADSTS50012 indicates that an invalid client secret was provided. Check if your current key is expired in the Azure Portal and try generating a new one.